# clear page cache when language changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, localization, multilingual

I have my .net web site set up to cache rendered pages in the browser.

My site is multi lingual so when the user selects a different language on the site, I want to the browser cache to be invalidated.

Is this something I set up when the request header or something I can trigger when the user changes their language?

I have set up the caching of the site in my web.config.

Comment: You can not (should not be allowed) to influence that. Just serve up a different css, js; Most usually the domain is qualified (en.wewbserver.com) or the url base is prefixed: (webserver.com/en/page.aspx); this is foolproof and doesn't depend on hackery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually know how you did the switching... Let's assume that you know when certain user changes his/her language. If you do, you can set Last-Modified header in your HTTP Response for current date and it should invalidate the response.

You may want to play with Content-Language header as well. I am not aware of browser support (need to test it actually). Theoretically, how I understand it, it should affect browser caching policy; new language content should be loaded and cached for the future.